# compile c++ file in linux terminal: string_view : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux

I have gcc (Cadence) 4.8.3. And I want to compile a c++ file which has an include string_view. When I compile the file:

```
g++ script.cpp
```

the following error occurs:

```
script.cpp:4:23: fatal error: string_view: No such file or directory
   #include <string_view>
                       ^
   compilation terminated.
```

I tried upgrading my gcc version but I couldn't.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5

sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

My question is how can I fix this problem, how can I upgrade my gcc version or is there an alternative that can replace the string_view library.

The .cpp script is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include<cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#define FEATURE 27
  double get_value(std::string_view value_str,double* smons) {
    std::map<std::string, double *> arrays_names {
    {"smons", smons}
    };
    auto name_end_pos = value_str.find('[');
    auto name = value_str.substr(0, name_end_pos);

    auto index_end_pos = value_str.find(']');
    auto index_len = index_end_pos - name_end_pos - 1;
    std::string index_str{value_str.substr(name_end_pos + 1, index_len)};
    auto index = std::stoi(index_str);

    return arrays_names[std::string(name)][index];
}

double evaluate_expression(const std::string& expr,double* smons) {

  double a;
  if (expr.size()==8)
  {
      a=get_value(expr.substr(0, 8),smons);
  }
  else if (expr.size()==9)
  {
      a=get_value(expr.substr(0, 9),smons);
  }
  else if (expr.size()==17)
  {
      a=get_value(expr.substr(0, 8),smons) * get_value(expr.substr(9, 8),smons);
  }
  else if (expr.size()==18)
  {
      a=get_value(expr.substr(0, 8),smons) * get_value(expr.substr(9, 9),smons);
  }
  else if (expr.size()==19)
  {
      a=get_value(expr.substr(0, 9),smons) * get_value(expr.substr(10, 9),smons);
  }

  return
    a;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to update your compiler.  `std::string_view` [is not available in GCC until version 7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17#C.2B.2B17_library_features#C.2B.2B17_library_features).

Answer (score 0):

`std::string_view` is a C++17 feature which your ancient GCC version does not support. You need a more up-to-date compiler and once you have that you need to enable C++17 support (usually by passing the command line argument `-std=c++17` (or use a newer standard version if you can)).